# Javascript - run for-loop with promises

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parse-platform, promise

I have a javascript script that I am running on parse.com that send a push notification to a user. I have the script almost done. Right now it will send a push with the query set to where I have it. So here are the restraints I have on it right now.

```
testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)'); 
testItemsQuery.equalTo('meal','LUNCH');
```

But now I have 2 variables

```
var schoolArray = ['Union College (NY)', 'University of Albany'];
var mealArray = ['LUNCH','DINNER'];
```

And I want it too loop through this script a total of 4 times. I first want it to loop through for both schools and then loop through each meal. So the most basic version of code would look like this.

```
var schoolArray = ['Union College (NY)', 'University of Albany'];
var mealArray = ['LUNCH','DINNER'];

for (var i = 0; i < schoolArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < mealArray.length; j++) {
         //insert all my other code here
    }
}
```

Here is my script which makes async requests to parse.com so that is why the for loops aren't working because I think I need to use some promises. Heres the code I want inside the for loop:

```
    function SendPush(installationId, msg) {

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('objectId', installationId);
    Parse.Push.send({
      where: query,
      data: {alert: msg}
    });
} 
var schoolArray = ['Union College (NY)', 'University of Albany'];
var mealArray = ['LUNCH','DINNER'];

var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
var UserFavorites = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");   
var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItem);


testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)'); //I want to loop through both schools for both meals
testItemsQuery.equalTo('meal','LUNCH');


var groupedAlerts = {};
testItemsQuery.each(function(testItem) {
    var item = testItem.get('item');
    var school = testItem.get('school');
    var userFavoritesQuery = new Parse.Query(UserFavorites); 
    userFavoritesQuery.include('user');
    userFavoritesQuery.equalTo('item', item);
    userFavoritesQuery.equalTo('school', school);

    return userFavoritesQuery.each(function(userFavorite) {

        //console.log(userFavorite);
        var user = userFavorite.get('user');
        if(user){
            var instId = user.get('installation').id;
            //console.log(instId);
            if(!groupedAlerts[instId]) {
                groupedAlerts[instId] = [];
            }
            var  meal = testItem.get('meal').toLowerCase();
            var m = userFavorite.get('item') + " is being served for " + meal + " at " + testItem.get('schoolMenu');
            groupedAlerts[instId].push(m);
        }
    });
}).then(function () {
    var alerts = [];
    for(var key in groupedAlerts) {
        alerts.push({
            installationId: key,
            alerts: groupedAlerts[key],
        });
        // Send push notifications
        SendPush(key, groupedAlerts[key].join());
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!!!

Comment: What doesn't work if you just put the code in the loops? Do you want the async steps to run sequentially or in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to scope what you labeled // all my other code here correctly.  If you wrap it in a function:

```
function schoolMealPush(school, meal) {
  // Really all your other code here
}
```

Then in your interior for loop just call that function

```
for (var i = 0; i < schoolArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < mealArray.length; j++) {
     schoolMealPush(schoolArray[i], mealArray[j]);
  }
}
```

You should be in business.  No need for promises..although promises could be used to know when all pushes are complete.  Just return the promise created by testItemsQuery.each and store each returned promise in an array.  Then using whatever promise lib you can do a .all

```
var promiseArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < schoolArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < mealArray.length; j++) {
     promiseArray.push(schoolMealPush(schoolArray[i], mealArray[j]));
  }
}
bluebird.all(promiseArray)
  .spread( function(){
    console.log('SendPush called for all values');
  });
```